# If a GPU branch needs to traverse both if condition branches, is it always inefficient?

Tags: graphics, fragment, gpu, glsl, shader

I could be more verbose with my question, but I'll try to ask it by example instead.

In a fragment shader, my understanding is that:

```
...
if(condition)
{
    /* loads of expensive work */
}
else
{
    /* loads of expensive work */
}
...
```

will run as quickly as one might naïvely expected if the condition evaluates uniformly over all fragments. However, it won't perform well in all other scenarios because the two cases for the condition will need to be run sequentially (because of a shared program counter within an SIMD unit?).

However, does that mean that something like:

```
...
if(condition)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    /* loads of expensive work */
}
...
```

would only maybe cost the price of some kind of context switches in the worst case and barely hit performance?

I think I'm asking because I've heard people tend to try and avoid branching with a non-uniform condition to save on performance, but could it be perfectly acceptable from a performance standpoint in the second case (and maybe with some other "light" load in one branch)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put,

Your videocard will scedule your shader to run on a bunch of cores. All these shaders have to run in sync. So if the condition is false on one of them it will stall all the cores.